# How do I truncate a string from a specific character in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `'Basingstoke & Deane'` and I would like to check for the `'&'` symbol and cut the string from (and including) that point.

So my input would be: `'Basingstoke & Deane'`

And the output would be: `'Basingstoke '`

I can search for the `'&'` fine using `$string =~ /&/` and can replace/delete it using `s/&//`, but I'm having a mental block of how to delete `&` and all characters after it. The extra space left over does not matter.

This is one of many strings, so thus a generic solution would be best. Apologies if this has been asked before, I've seen a lot of questions about truncating a string using `substr` and questions searching for a specific string and so on, but nothing quite what I'm looking for. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How about `s/([^&]*)&/$1/`

Comment: Or, simpler, `s/&.*//` perhaps?

Comment: Ah great answers all, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string =~ s/&.*//s;
```

Will delete the rest of the string, including newlines.

Comment: @bladepanthera, Makes `.` match any code point (as opposed to all except newline).

Comment: @bladepanthera http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers Just like ikegami just said, it makes the wildcard match any character. Normally, it does not match newline.

Comment: Ah really? Interesting. I didn't notice an effect, but one string is probably not a good test case. Great answer!

Comment: @bladepanthera It makes sure that if you have a multiline string, such as `"Foo & Bar\nBaz"` it does strip everything after `&`, including what comes after newline.

Answer (score 2):

You could also find the index of the `&` and use the `substr` function to take a portion of the string:

```
my $string    = 'Basingstoke & Deane';
my $amp_index = index($string, '&');

print substr($string, 0, $amp_index);
# Basingstoke
```

Courtesy of @TLP (substr as an lvalue):

```
substr($string, index($string, '&')) = ""
```

Comment: `substr($string, index($string, '&')) = "";` is also a neat trick.

Comment: @TLP Yeah, I forgot that you can use it as an lvalue. I'll add it above.

Comment: Note: Those fail badly when `&` isn't present. They're also slower than the alternatives (especially lvalue `substr`), but not so much so as to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
my ($prefix) = $string =~ /^([^&]*)/s;

my ($prefix) = split /&/, $string;      # Slightly faster, IIRC
```

In-place:

```
$string =~ s/&.*//s;
```

Comment: The caret is irrelevant in your first example. Edit: the beginning of line anchor, that is.

Comment: @TLP, True, but it's a good practice. Not only does it tell the reader you expect it to match at the beginning of the string, it can avoid lots of backtracking in similar expressions.

Comment: It certainly does not hurt, if indeed the point is to match from the beginning, and if it is, it is better to include it, as you say.